# Custom print function that wraps print()

Tags: python, printing

How can I wrap `print()` so that I can add arbitrary strings to the beginning and end of the things that are passed as arguments to get printed?

```
def xprint(*args):
    print("XXX", *args, "XXX")
xprint("hi", "yo", 4)
```

doesn't work.

Basically, I want my custom function `xprint()` to work like `print()` but add `'XXX'` to the beginning and end of every output.

Answer (score 26):

Will work for python 2 and 3 when there are no keyword arguments

```
def xprint(*args):
    print( "XXX"+" ".join(map(str,args))+"XXX")

In [5]: xprint("hi", "yo", 4)
XXXhi yo 4XXX
```

For the python 3 `print()` function (or when using `print_function` from `__future__` in python 2), keyword arguments may be present as well. To ensure these are passed use the form

```
def xprint(*args, **kwargs):
    print( "XXX"+" ".join(map(str,args))+"XXX", **kwargs)
```

Comment: For Python3, it should be `def xprint(*args, **kwargs): ...`, no?

Comment: @wjandrea - Good point! I've edited this with the clarification.

Comment: Overall a good solution but note that this won't support non ascii unicode + this don't support print ending with comma to stay on the same line.

Comment: @RonenNess, what error are you getting with non-ascii, also py3 or py2? If it is py2, you should either be prepending the string with a `u`/decoding etc.. For py3 you should have very little issue bar your shell limitations like you enjoy on windows, you can also implement the sep arg in py3 or import the print_function in py2, there is no limitation to what you want to add it terms of how print works.

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham I'm talking about Python 2, ofc, where all unicode / str problems reside :) Anyway I must correct myself its something that shouldn't work with regular print either, but with IDLE it does because IDLE works a little differently with print. With that said, consider the following input: print(u'\u05d1\u05d3\u05d9\u05e7\u05d4') - it works with print, but throw exception with xprint. Anyway this is in IDLE, in shell it throws exception in both print and xprint (encoding is needed), so this is a non issue imo.

Comment: If you want the `sep`-keyword to work, do this: def xprint(*args, sep=" ", **kwargs): print("XXX"+sep.join(map(str,args))+"XXX", **kwargs)`

Answer (score 2):

You can do the same thing without changing print function name. Just add below code in your script.

```
xprint = print


def print(*args, **kwargs):
    # do whatever you want to do
    xprint('statement before print')
    xprint(*args, **kwargs)


print(f'hello')
```

Comment: Probably the best, hack-iest, compact way. Very cool.

Answer (score 1):

```
def xprint(*args, **kwargs):
    #  put a generator on all elements in args that will
    #  use string.format to prepend / append XXX to all args
    args = ( 'XXX' '{}' 'XXX'.format(i)  for i in args) 
    
    # pass it on to print()
    print(*args, **kwargs)
  
>>> xprint("hi", "yo", 4)
XXXhiXXX XXXyoXXX XXX4XXX
```

So what are **keyword arguments**?
Well just in case you wanna add more fancy decoration to the text modding the standard separator you can do that like this:

```
>>> xprint("hi", "yo", 4,  Sep="=- -=")
XXXhiXXX=- -=XXXyoXXX=- -=XXX4XXX
```

By passing on `**kwargs` you'll enable xprint to retain that functionality.
Why I mention this? Seems that most authors of answers here don't know or care about.
Optional you may add the line

```
kwargs["file"]=sys.stderr
```

into `xprint` to make it output text to `stderr` instead of `stdout`.
In most cases I wrap `print()` for that purpose.

... and another inconspicuous neat thing that's worth mentioning here is
**generator comprehension**. These generators are a functional programming thing. Instead of immediately apply changes to the data/memory a generator just 'hooks on' the iterator for that data. *To be more precise a generator expression just return a new iterator.* That iterator is used to later to fetch the actual data in a `for .. in .. loop`. Only when the actual data is read the generator gets applied.
That may significant reduce the amount of data copy around in memory can so can lead to big savings in memory usage.

Changing the line to:

```
    args = [ 'XXX' '{}' 'XXX'.format(i)  for i in args]
```

*Note: just the brackets change from () to [].*
It's will turn the whole thing into a **List comprehension** expression. That will do work the more 'conservative' way.  Return a new list with the changes and overwrite the old args list.

Comment: Best answer here! +1

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use this code as python user define module. save this file as **custom_print.py**

```
from termcolor import colored

xprint = print
def print(*args, **kwargs):
    # print args
    if len(args) > 0:
        xprint("|> {}".format(*args))
    # print Kwargs
    count_ = 0
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        # for black and white 
        # xprint("In [{}]:: {}\t {}".format(count_, key, value))
    
        # For colored output
        xprint(colored("In [{}]::".format(count_), "red"), colored(" 
        {}\t".format(key), "green"), colored(":{}".format(value), "blue"))
        count_ += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # demo Testing

    # demo 1
    print("hello World")

    # Demo 2
    print(100, 500,
       name="Nitish Sharma",
       age=25,
       city="Motihari",
       email= "example@gmail.com"
      )
```

Now Create a **main.py** and import *custom_print* Like

```
from custom_print import *
 
print("Hello World",
      name="Nitish Kumar",
      age=25,
      city="Motihari")
```

**:: OUTPUT**

```
|> Hello World
In [0]:: name    :Nitish Kumar
In [1]:: age     :25
In [2]:: city    :Motihari
```

---

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gG1jV.png)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
def xprint(*args):
    args = ("XXX",)+args+("XXX",)
    print(*args)
xprint("hi", "yo", 4)
```

output is `XXX hi yo 4 XXX`

Comment: on python 2.x this gives invalid syntax.