# How to override the builtin method "print()"

Tags: python, printing

I need to customize the `print()`, so that it does something else besides printing what I want. Is there a way to override it?

Comment: `def my_print(*args): ...; print = my_print`. but why would you want to do that?

Comment: I don't think it works like this

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: just add anything I print to a file.txt that I will give the path to it

Comment: that is what [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#module-logging) is for...

Comment: can you explain more @hiroprotagonist

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect stdout to a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675728/redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-python)

Comment: It does @FilipMüller but I also want to print it

Comment: And why do you need to override `print`? Why don't you just create a new function that calls `print` inside?

Comment: there are a lot of printing, so I am not into creating a custom function if there is a way to override print

Comment: `python myscript.py | tee logfile.txt`. No change to the script needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one option is to use [`contextlib.redirect_stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout):

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

with open('file.txt', 'a') as file, redirect_stdout(file):
    print('hello')
```

if you need both printing and saving to a file, this may work:

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
from sys import stdout
from io import StringIO

class MyOutput(StringIO):
    def __init__(self, file):
        super().__init__()
        self.file = file

    def write(self, msg):
        stdout.write(msg)
        self.file.write(msg)

with open('file.txt', 'a') as file, redirect_stdout(MyOutput(file=file)):
    print('hello')
```

Comment: okay, but I am not into creating a local method for this. I would just do it with print, without the need of contextlib

Comment: you are creating a local method in the accepted answer... this here does not create a function - it creates a context and within that context all `print` statemements (and everything that writes to `sys.stdout`) is redirected. imho this is cleaner than the accepted answer.

Comment: but your code will also be used in a local method.

Comment: As  I want to both print and save anything I print

Comment: so intead of print("hello") it will be print(statement) where statement will be a paramter

Comment: And I don't want to write this block erverytime

Comment: But it's also useful so I will upvote you

Comment: no. you do that **once** at the beginning of your program and call your functions inside that context. and you *can* do both: print and safe. you'd need to write some additional code for that.

Comment: oh you mean I will replace print("Hello") with my main function, right?

Comment: exactly! that is what i mean.

Comment: okay, sorry for the misunderstood

Comment: your answer isn't working, it either saves the print, or print without saving,.

Comment: as i said, you need to add some more code. i added an example.

Comment: it says : Expected type '_T_io', got 'MyOutput' instead

Comment: that is just the type checker. it would have run anyway. but i fixed it in order so silence the type checker. maybe this could have been done in a cleverer way?

Comment: one thing is that it only get what is written inside the with block, and not any functions inside it, say if a function prints something, it will not get what this function prints

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://faster-cpython.readthedocs.io/mutable.html) is A Page That Will Help You With Overriding Functions!

Here is A Way To Override `print`! (Making a New `print`)

Code:

```
from __future__ import print_function

try:
    import __builtin__
except ImportError:
    import builtins as __builtin__

def print(*args, **kwargs):
    """My custom print() function."""
    __builtin__.print('your text')
    return __builtin__.print(*args, **kwargs)
```

print()

Output:
`your text`

The Line `__builtin__.print('your text')` would Print 'Your Text', you can put other function Also Instead of Print, it would Print Your Given Text also As The Return Line Says It to, it used the built in print function!

The Second Thing That you can Do is That You Can Remove The Return Line so The Function wouldn't Print Anything To The Console

Hope This Helps

Comment: Hey Omar What Do You Exactly Want The Code To Do?

Comment: `from __future__ import print_function` is only required in python 2. in python 3 there is no need for that.

Comment: Hiro, I did it for Python 2 And Python 3 Both, For The Ease of Omar!

Comment: i hope people have stopped using python 2 nowadays... but ok, +1.

Comment: At Least I Helped Omar!

Comment: i was not criticizing your answer as not helpful! that was more a comment in general than about your answer. sorry if you feel offended...

Comment: No No, Its ok! Thanks For Your Assistance!

Answer (score 0):

You can override the print() method but you have to create class and then override the "**str**" dunder method (print() uses "**str**" implementation in backend). Here is the code.

```
a = 2
print(a)

class abc:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = x
    def __str__(self):
        return "The value is " + str(self.x)

a = abc(2)
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
DEBUG=1 # only print when debugging
import datetime

_print = print  # preserve original
def print(*args, **kwargs):
    if DEBUG:
        _print(f"{datetime.datetime.now()} ", end='')
        _print(*args, **kwargs)
    else:
        pass

# ---- regular print usage
print("abc", x, y, z)
```

Got the idea from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70915521/2612429